# Is there a database agnostic way to determine common SQL errors in JDBC?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I'm implementing a lightweight ORM layer on top of JDBC for use with several different database implementations.

Is there a database agnostic way to determine common SQL errors?

(such as...)

- foreign key violation
- unique violation
- check violation
- deadlock detected

Using PostgreSQL these can be identified by `SQLException#getSQLState()`, but these error codes do not match the corresponding in MySQL.

Though a general approach to the problem is preferred, a driver-specific solutions seems to be required.

Comment: SQLSTATE valus *should* be vendor independent because they are defined in the SQL standard (ISO/IEC 9075). But not all DBMS obey the standard. I guess you will need to have some mapping yourself (vendor SQLCODE to some internal number)

Comment: The SQL States cannot be used at all in some implementations. It seems that a mix of Error Codes and SQL States is minimum to bridge the gap.

Comment: That's what I meant with *should* ;)

Comment: And in addition to the SQL States defined in ISO/IEC 9075, vendors are allowed to define their own SQL States (generally for cases outside of the standard though)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) manages this.  They've done the work to make it easier for you.  Check out its JDBC package.

Spring was purchased by VMWare a while back, but they still make their framework available as open source.

Comment: Just to complete the answer. [SQLExceptionTranslator Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-SQLExceptionTranslator)

Comment: We have already looked into their representation of the translation, which uses SQLException.getErrorCode() or SQLException.getSQLState() determined by the product name. https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/3.2.x/spring-jdbc/src/main/resources/org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml

Comment: The Spring solution has a very rough categorisation of errors, and the implementation is heavily layered. So while it is not a suitable choice for our lightweight product, it may suffice for others with the same intent, especially if they already depend on Spring. I'll leave the question open until we find a proper solution or implement one ourselves. I'll give the upvote that you deserve for valid pointers.

Answer (score 0):

While the solution in Spring Framework has some support for classification of known SQL errors the solution is heavily layered and also in part incorrect.

We felt the need for a custom implementation and came up with [`com.jajja.jorm.Dialect`](https://github.com/jajja/jorm/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jajja/jorm/Dialect.java), the dialect specific elements of [jORM](https://github.com/jajja/jorm), a lightweight Java ORM. The data is based on tests with specific versions of SQL engines. Other versions of the engines may differ in representation of errors, and some engines have not yet been examined.

**Note** unfortunately there is no database agnostic alternative for SQL error classification in JDBC.